Material applied to object, but inconsistent appearance
I'm new to Blender and I'm following ArtStudio "Texturing & Cinematic Lighting In Blender".
I created a PBR wood material (base color, ao, roughness and normals), but when applied to certain objects I get inconsistent results among faces: some parts are much lighter than others. It looks like ambient occlusion is somewhere ignored (see material preview and rendered views).


I already checked that the same material is applied to all faces, face orientation and that texture coordinates in the material is set to UV.
Moreover, in the UV editing view, you can see that while the two selected UVs have the same dimension, textures appear differently on the objects.
I can easily solve this second thing scaling one UVs more than the other (while I would still expect them to look the same), why do I get so different lighting results on different faces of the same objects?

Thanks for your help!

Hello could you please share your file?

Of course. If hope I'll share it the right way!
The packed file is about 350 MB, so instead I zipped the .blend file along with the PBR textures and the HDRI I used and uploaded it to file.io
link

Switch your normal map from sRGB to Non-Color:

